# Getting different const values from a stateless component

Tags: react-native

I'm a newbie in react native. Sorry if my question looks stupid. I want to write every http url in a file and access them where needed. How can I do that?

for instance I've AllUrl.js file, I want to write the following urls in it

```
const baseUrl = "https://amrita.com/";
const secondaryUrl = "https://google.com";
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

Then I want to access the individual url string where needed.

eg:

```
import AllUrls from "./AllUrls";
export default class Home extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
            fetch(AllUrls.baseUrl) //I want to do this ie. call baseUrl const here
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({
          homeList: responseJson.homeLIst,
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert(error);
      });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
            _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
        );
    }
}
```

How can I do it? How can I access baseUrl string from AllUrl.js to Home.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to import something from another file, you have to export them.

For example: in AllUrl.js file.

```
export const baseUrl = "https://amrita.com/";
export const secondaryUrl = "https://google.com";
```

Then import them in another file

```
import {baseUrl, secondaryUrl} from "./AllUrls";
export default class Home extends React.Component {}
```

I recommend you should take sometime for learning Javascript syntact before make the mobile app with React Native. Above code is ES5/ES6 Javscript. :))

Cheer!

Answer (score 1):

According to your situation you need to export all `variables` as `default`

```
const baseUrl = "https://amrita.com/";
const secondaryUrl = "https://google.com";

export default {
  baseUrl,
  secondaryUrl
}
```

and use them as

```
import AllUrls from "./AllUrls";

AllUrls.baseUrl
AllUrls.secondaryUrl
```